# MbUnit - Terminate Test from within SetUp method

Tags: c#, mbunit, gallio

I want to Terminate my test with a specific outcome from within the SetUp Method.

I have tried both SilentTestException and Assert.Terminate and Assert.TerminateSilently but the actual Test method seems to be executed regardless.

You can reproduce this behavior with the following code: https://gist.github.com/2857816

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/gallio-user/jQby62ak8es